# What is this? I just pulled this out of my cat almost like a pimple

Tags: cats, health, diseases, parasites

[image: .]

is about the length of my pinky nail and it looks like it’s leaving an open hole with no blood. Please help me!

Comment: where on your cat did you find it,more information please is it hard or soft,is your cat an indoor cat.

Comment: If still in doubt, bring it to your vet on the next visit and ask them. And/or ask if you could drop it off for the lab to check.

Answer (score 3):

I have asked several people about what it might be, and it has to be a cutaneous horn.

A cutaneous horn is made of keratin - the same material as in your cat's claws.

Cutaneous horn and the formation of them can be an autoimmune reaction and is in the same family of reactions as psoriasis.

Reference: http://vetbook.org/wiki/cat/index.php?title=Cutaneous_horn

More information: https://www.vetinfo.com/cfoot.html

You need to see a vet for diagnosis and treatment of this problem.

Credit to Rebecca for her input to my question about this.

Answer (score 0):

Where was this pulled out on the body? I have a cat that has an inverted nipple. This nipple gets filled with gunk. After a while a lump forms at that nipple under the skin and I will gently squeeze it to release the built up gunk. This is EXACTLY what this looks like. Identical. Cutaneous horns are hard. This gunk, think nipple cheese because that's what it is, is soft. And its harmless.